# Bouncing img in div game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my code in javascript. I want to edit code to make my mini game.

This is the original code I'm trying to edit. It's about bouncing balls. When you press the button the balls starts bouncing. The balls are in random position and every ball is moving randomly. When they are about to escape the border they are returning. Everything in this code works perfect.
**Original code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    #border {height:500px; width:500px; border:1px solid grey; margin:auto; position:relative}
    b {display:block; height:10px; width:10px; border-radius:5px; background:red; position:absolute}
    h1,div {text-align:center; margin:10px}
</style>
</head>
<body>

</body>

<h1>Balls</h1>
<div id='border'>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
</div>

<div>
    <button onclick="run=false"> Stop </button>
    <button onclick="run=true;start()"> Start </button>
</div>


<script>
        var b=document.getElementsByTagName('B');
        var run=false;
        var i;
        for(i=0;i<b.length;i++)
        {
            b[i].x=Math.random()*490;
            b[i].y=Math.random()*490;

            b[i].vx=Math.random()*20-10;
            b[i].vy=Math.random()*20-10;

            b[i].style.left=b[i].x+"px";
            b[i].style.top =b[i].y+"px";
        }

    function start()
    {
        var i;
        for(i=0;i<b.length;i++)
        {
            b[i].x+=b[i].vx;
            b[i].y+=b[i].vy;

            if(b[i].x>490 || b[i].x<0)  b[i].vx*=-1;
            if(b[i].y>490 || b[i].y<0)  b[i].vy*=-1;

            b[i].style.left=b[i].x+"px";
            b[i].style.top =b[i].y+"px";
        }

        if(run)
            setTimeout(start,20);

    }
</script>

</html>
```

I want to replace the balls with images. I think I did it but it doesn't work at all. **Images are always in the same position. When I press the button to move them, images are moving in the same direction. Images are escaping from border (they should bounce on the walls and return).**
**My edit:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    #border {height:500px; width:500px; border:1px solid grey; margin:auto; position:relative}
    img {display:block; height:10px; width:10px; position:absolute}
    h1,div {text-align:center; margin:10px}
</style>
</head>
<body>

</body>

<h1>Balls</h1>
<div id='border'>
    <img src="http://www.doktoranci.uj.edu.pl/image/image_gallery?uuid=8de2ed31-63f2-42f3-83fd-8fc0b7c48975&groupId=1167150&t=1287521328354">
    <img src="http://www.doktoranci.uj.edu.pl/image/image_gallery?uuid=8de2ed31-63f2-42f3-83fd-8fc0b7c48975&groupId=1167150&t=1287521328354">
    <img src="http://www.doktoranci.uj.edu.pl/image/image_gallery?uuid=8de2ed31-63f2-42f3-83fd-8fc0b7c48975&groupId=1167150&t=1287521328354">
</div>

<div>
    <button onclick="run=false"> Stop </button>
    <button onclick="run=true; start()"> Start </button>
</div>


<script>
        var b=document.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
        var run=false;
        var i;
        for(i=0; i<b.length; i++)
        {
            b[i].x=Math.random()*490;
            b[i].y=Math.random()*490;

            b[i].vx=Math.random()*20-10;
            b[i].vy=Math.random()*20-10;

            b[i].style.left=b[i].x+"px";
            b[i].style.top =b[i].y+"px";
        }

    function start()
    {
        var i;
        for(i=0; i<b.length; i++)
        {
            b[i].x+=b[i].vx;
            b[i].y+=b[i].vy;

            if(b[i].x>490 || b[i].x<0)  b[i].vx*=-1;
            if(b[i].y>490 || b[i].y<0)  b[i].vy*=-1;

            b[i].style.left=b[i].x+"px";
            b[i].style.top =b[i].y+"px";
        }

        if(run)
            setTimeout(start,20);

    }
</script>

</html>
```

I want my images to behavior like the balls in original code.
You're my only hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `<img>`, use

```
b {background-image: url("http://www.doktoranci.uj.edu.pl/image/image_gallery?uuid=8de2ed31-63f2-42f3-83fd-8fc0b7c48975&groupId=1167150&t=1287521328354");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right top;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the code is not working with `img` tags is outlined in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement):

> `HTMLImageElement.x` **Read only** Returns a long representing the
>   horizontal offset from the nearest layer. This property mimics an old
>   Netscape 4 behavior.
>
> `HTMLImageElement.y` **Read only**   Returns a long
>   representing the vertical offset from the nearest layer. This property
>   mimics an old Netscape 4 behavior.

As a work around you can use [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) on `b` tags or change the coordinates property names to i.e. `currentX` and `currentY`